# SQL with MVC 4 WebAPI

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, odata, asp.net-web-api

I've found enough MVC 4 API samples that use a hard-coded array as the data source, but am having trouble finding a simple example with and SQL query.

I have this model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and I would like to construct a controller that returns a list of Person using this database query:

```
select id, name from names order by name
```

If it matters, the connection string to the database:

```
Server=sql12;Database=Mydb;Integrated Security=true;"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: write a method which executes the query and read the results and fill list of Person objects and return. Call that method in your action method.

Comment: Thought about doing that, a bit awkward, last resort, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Entity Framework examples for ASP.NET MVC. There are several tutorials that apply to what you're doing.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc

Comment: Is there not a simple ADO.NET solution? Or does WebAPI require the use of a new data access paradigm?

Comment: @Metaphor: No you can use any data access technology as per your wish.